# DOM changes inside content loaded via Ajax

Tags: jquery

I'm loading a bunch of content via jQuery Ajax, now I want to change an img src attribute inside this loaded content.

Using `.click` is obviously not working, to target Ajax loaded content I used `.on`:

```
$("#user_list").on('click','.block_user', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr("src", "path_to_img_and_name.png");
});
```

This works just fine. The image gets replaced as it should, my problem arises when I put this change inside a **NEW** jquery ajax call:

```
$("#user_list").on('click','.block_user', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var bstatus=$(this).attr("bstatus"),
    user_id=$(this).attr("user_id");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'main/change_user_status',
        data: {
            bstatus: bstatus,
            user_id: user_id
        },
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output){
            $(this).attr("src", "images/"+output+"_block_user.png");
            $(this).attr("bstatus", output);
        }
    });
});
```

This isn't working at all.

- The AJAX call is turning successfully.
- The scope is right, so are the paths to my img.
- This only happens if my click function has an AJAX call

It seems like the original content is being reloaded somehow, anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the scope of the $(this) selector. You could use something like this

```
$("#user_list").on('click','.block_user', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var bstatus=$(this).attr("bstatus"),
user_id=$(this).attr("user_id");

var elem = $(this)

$.ajax({
    url: 'main/change_user_status',
    data: {
        bstatus: bstatus,
        user_id: user_id
    },
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(output){
        elem.attr("src", "images/"+output+"_block_user.png");
        elem.attr("bstatus", output);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Please see my answer to techfoobar, it's not a scope issue.

Comment: are you sure you are entering the success function?

Comment: Yes, alerts and console logs show it. In fact, if I log elem.attr("src", "images/"+output+"_block_user.png"); it shows the correct code, except the image doesn't change...

Comment: Does the bstatus attr change?

Comment: It changes on the success, as soon as the success ends, it goes back to the original value...

Comment: I tested this by alerting bstatus on the click event and after success.

Comment: So... another person linked to the project decided to put an ajaxComplete handler in one of the success functions... dohhh

Comment: At least you got it. That's a lot of pain though

Answer (score 0):

Use the `context` attribute of `$.ajax()` which determines the value of `this` inside the `success` callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'main/change_user_status',
    context: this, // here 'this' refers to the #user_list that was clicked
    ...
    success: function(output) {
        // here 'this' refers to what we set as 'context'
        $(this).attr("src", "images/"+output+"_block_user.png");
        $(this).attr("bstatus", output);
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ - Scroll down a little to read about `context`

Comment: Hello. I pasted the wrong code up there.. I did actually try context, and also tried putting the original scope in another variable, no luck. Still not working.